# Plotting shades in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-science

I've created a `DataFrame` with a `Timeseries` in it. I want to create two line graphs, which works actually fine. But when I try to add a `.fill()`, `.fill_between()` method to fill the area between the to line graphs, it dosen't work out.

I hope you guys can spot the problem and give me a hint what I have missed. Thanks for your support.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/dfde0bd5fafd6b92b878722b7a0dcec142e04e569a403041ee9cba05.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Create useful DataFrame
df2 = df[df['Element'] == 'TMAX']
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Data_Value':'MAXV'}).drop(['ID','Element'], axis=1)
df3 = df[df['Element'] == 'TMIN']
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'Data_Value':'MINV'}).drop(['ID','Element'], axis=1)
df2 = df2.merge(df3, on='Date')
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])


#set index as datetime
df2 = df2.set_index('Date').drop(df2[df2['MINV']==0]).dropna().sort_index()
df2 = df2.ix['2007-1-1':'2008-12-31']

#plot
plt.style.context(('dark_background'))
df2.plot(figsize=(30,20))
plt.fill_between(df2['MAXV'],df2['MINV'], color='b', alpha=0.2)

plt.show()
```

Output:[image]

Output `df2` (not all data, just to show the structure):
[image]

Comment: Didn't `fill_between ` need first x-data as parameter and then y1 and y2?` plt.fill_between(df.index, df2['MAXV'],df2[... `In your case

Comment: :D. Completly true. Thanks.